# Angular proxy config refuses to route correctly. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have set up the simplest implementation of an Angular 14 service consuming a .NET web API, yet for some reason I can never get the service to return anything other than an HTTP 404 error.

I've tested the API controller manually, and that's definitely returning the data I want, but for some reason the API call from Angular never seems to get routed.

I've tried every configuration I can think of in `proxy.conf.js` but this is what I have at the moment:

```
{
    context: [
      "/test",
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7265/test",
    secure: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
  }
```

As I understand it, the proxy will take any request to `https://localhost:4200/test` (my localhost) and route it through to `https://localhost:7265/test` but this never seems to happen. When I load the console, this is what I see:

[image: Screenshot]

It doesn't even seem to be logging anything about the proxy either (which is what the `logLevel` setting does as I understand). Here is the setup I have:

proxy.conf.js:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/test",
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7265/test",
    secure: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angularapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angularapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angularapp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angularapp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angularapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My app component API call:

```
http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('/test').subscribe(result => {
      console.log('contact', result);
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

And then finally my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using webapi.Interfaces;
using webapi.Models;
using webapi.Services;
using System.Text;

namespace webapi.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ContactController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<ContactController> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;

    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    public ContactController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<ContactController> logger, IEmailService elasticEmailService)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailService = elasticEmailService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/test")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, when I query `https://localhost:7265/test` directly, I get the JSON feed back, but a 404 when querying through Angular.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Won't that be going to `/test/test` on the backend? Do you get any logs from .NET? What happens if you hit `:4200/test` from _outside_ Angular?

Comment: I've tried both '/' and '/test' and neither has made a difference. If I access that URL outside of angular (using the same domain) it gives me the same 404 message

Comment: And what do you see in the backend logs? Or the proxy logs (they _won't_ be in the browser, that's not where the proxy runs)?

Comment: Okay I've just noticed it's logging an error in the angular console - looks like it might be a certificate error. Will look into it and get back to you! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where the problem is. Maybe try removing the `/test` from your target and/or setting `secure` to false. But if that doesn't help, here is how you can troubleshoot.

In the browser developer tools (network) you won't see the redirected URL by the proxy but the originally called URL instead.

If you want to see if the proxy redirect is applied correctly you can see it in the logs by using the `--verbose` option.

```
$ npm start -- --verbose
```

Here is how I setup my proxy. (I am using json format)

```json
{
  "/test": {
    "target": "https://localhost:7265",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

(Set `secure` to false, if you get a CERT error.)

Now, if there is a problem with the proxy routing, you should see an error in the logs (with `--verbose` and debug log level). It should look like this:

```
"[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] GET /test/some/optional/path -> https://localhost:7265"
```

**Summary:**
So, if there is nothing wrong in the "verbose" logs and also no errors show up while testing (making the requests), it might be a problem with the Backend endpoint.

**Side Note:**
You should not use that proxy for other than development (at least not on production). So you should change your angular.json to apply the proxy only for development.

UPDATE: I played around with it and figured out, that the path is completely applied to the new target. So you don't need the `/test`. I updated my proxy conf example accordingly.